# How can I make the ui text child to be ignored from the raw image trigger event?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a rawimage prefab and one of his childs is a ui text :

[image: Event trigger]

And the script that use the event trigger :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MouseHover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SaveLoad saveLoad;
    public SceneFader sceneFader;

    private bool loadGame = false;

    public void OnHover()
    {
        Debug.Log("Enter");

        loadGame = true;
    }
    public void OnHoverExit()
    {
        Debug.Log("Exit");

        loadGame = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(loadGame)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                StartCoroutine(sceneFader.FadeAndLoadScene(SceneFader.FadeDirection.In, "Game"));

                loadGame = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that even if there is a space between each of the raw images when I move the mouse over the raw images in the game view window when the mouse pointer is on the ui text at the bottom or on the same line of the ui text it's still showing "Enter" and it's showing "Exit" only when the mouse pointer leave the ui text.

Is there any way to keep the ui text child of the raw image but to ignore the ui text in the event trigger ?

Comment: I tried to uncheck the "Raycast target" on the ui text but still sometimes when moving the mouse pointer between the rawimages it keep showing "Enter" it's like sometimes the event is not detecting when leaving the current raw image area and keep showing "Enter" like there is no space between the raw images.

Comment: Unchecking raycast target is indeed how that is solved. If you're still getting enter events, then they're not coming from the text, and you should use your script to print the name of the hovered object to diagnose where the unwanted event is coming from.

Comment: How do I print the hover gameobject ? The function in the script OnHover is just a simple method.